# Why doesn't my setSetsValue increment inside my Input component?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state

I want to increment the value inside an input component I've created, it does work just for one click, then it just switches back and forth between 5 & 6 on every buttonpress that initiates the pressHandler. Why is that so?

Can this be a question about the defaultValues array itself or that my setSetsValue is completely wrong?

Shouldn't the value for defaultValues[0].sets.totalSets be incremented after each buttonpress? Or am I in the wrong for thinking something that absurd.

Thanks for any kind of help!

The code:

```js
let defaultValues = [
    {
      sets: { totalSets: "4" },
      work: { min: "00", sec: "50" },
      rest: { min: "00", sec: "30" },
    },
  ];

  const [setsValue, setSetsValue] = useState(defaultValues[0].sets.totalSets);

  const pressHandler = () => {
    defaultValues[0].sets.totalSets =
      parseInt(defaultValues[0].sets.totalSets) + 1;
    setSetsValue(defaultValues[0].sets.totalSets.toString());
  };
```

My input component:

```js
function AppInput({ defaultValue }) {
  return (
    <TextInput
      underlineColorAndroid={"white"}
      keyboardType="numeric"
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      editable={true}
      placeholderTextColor={"white"}
      style={styles.textInput}
    ></TextInput>
  );
}
```

Comment: What about change defaultValue to value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look this example

```js
let valueA = 1;
console.log(valueA); //log value
const handler = () => {
    valueA  = valueA + 1; //increase value
    setAnyStateValue(); //update state
  };
```

if you call `handler()` 100 times the `log results is : 1 !!!`
**why log don't increase ???**
because `handler()` will update state by function `setAnyStateValue()` and every time state is updated the component `rerender again` and the valueA declared again `let valueA = 1;`

what to do to slove this

soluion one

```js
setSetsValue(x => x + 1); //this will update value based on last value plus one
```

solution two

```js
  const pressHandler = () => {
    setSetsValue(parseInt(setsValue) + 1);
  };
```